# QGIS - Converting GEOPDF to MBTILE gives error "band 1 has no colour table"

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, mbtiles, geopdf

I'm trying to convert GEOPDF files to MBTiles using QGIS on mac. I'm using GDAL version 1.11.4, QGIS version 2.8.9. I am doing this by raster -> translate -> input layer GEOPDF file, output file MBTile file. I have tried setting expand to Grey, RGB and RGBA but they all give the same error. "band 1 has no colour table".

I have installed the GEOPDF Plugin for GDAL.

I have found questions with similar issues and they all point to using "1-Band Raster Colour Table" Plugin but this does not work with the current version of QGIS.

I tried reverting back to earlier version of QGIS but then I couldn't get QGIS to read GEOPDF files.

I can use QGIS to export geotiff files from the PDF files and then use Map tiler to get the MBTile but it would be much easier if I could just do it all on QGIS.

Comment: Can you give a link to a sample GeoPDF file?